Order WooCommerce Products By Product Attribute Value In Increasing Order
I have about 2,800 products in my woocommerce store. Each product has an attribute value called decimalwidth that represents the product width in decimal form. Some examples of these values are 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, etc.
I would like to have my product catalog page sorted from smallest width to largest width but am having trouble doing so.
I've tried various Chat GPT, Copilot, Perplexity code outputs that are supposed to be pasted into my functions.php file in my theme. I've also looked at other previous answers here and don't think any of them work for me either. All of the LLM outputs are pretty similar and none of them work unfortunately. I would appreciate any ideas or guidance on accomplishing this!
Everything keeps recommending along the lines of the below, but it doesn't work:
// Add custom sorting options for decimalwidth attribute
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_decimalwidth_orderby');

function custom_decimalwidth_orderby($args)
{
    $orderby_value = isset($_GET['orderby']) ? wc_clean(wp_unslash($_GET['orderby'])) : '';
    
    if ('decimalwidth' == $orderby_value) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num'; // Sorting by numeric value
        $args['order'] = 'ASC'; // Ascending order
        $args['meta_key'] = 'pa_decimalwidth'; // Meta key for decimalwidth attribute
    }
    
    return $args;
    }  


// Add custom sorting options to the dropdown
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_add_decimalwidth_orderby');

function custom_add_decimalwidth_orderby($sortby)
{
    $sortby['decimalwidth'] = __('Sort by Decimal Width', 'woocommerce');
    return $sortby;
}



Edit
Solved:
As someone pointed out, everything needed to be a meta value rather than a product attribute. I already had all the decimal values as a product attribute, so I could simply export the products, add a new column for meta that mirrored the product attribute column and import the new spreadsheet while updating the products based on SKU#.
Then by adding this code I had exactly what I wanted:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'add_custom_sorting_option' );

function add_custom_sorting_option( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['decimalwidth_asc'] = 'Width: Ascending';
    $sortby['decimalwidth_desc'] = 'Width: Descending';
    return $sortby;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_sorting_query_args', 10, 3 );

function custom_sorting_query_args( $args, $orderby, $order ) {
    switch ( $orderby ) {
        case 'decimalwidth_asc':
            $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
            $args['order'] = 'ASC';
            $args['meta_key'] = 'decimalwidth';
            break;
        case 'decimalwidth_desc':
            $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
            $args['order'] = 'DESC';
            $args['meta_key'] = 'decimalwidth';
            break;
    }
    return $args;
}


add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', 'custom_sorting_float_meta_query', 10, 6 );

function custom_sorting_float_meta_query( $sql, $queries, $type, $primary_table, $primary_id_column, $context ) {
    if ( ! empty( $context->query_vars['orderby'] ) && $context->query_vars['orderby'] == 'meta_value_num' ) {
        if ( ! empty( $context->query_vars['meta_key'] ) && $context->query_vars['meta_key'] == 'decimalwidth' ) {
            $sql['orderby'] = str_replace( 'ORDER BY', 'ORDER BY CAST(' . $primary_table . '.meta_value AS DECIMAL(10,2))', $sql['orderby'] );
        }
    }
    return $sql;
}


add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'custom_default_catalog_orderby');
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_catalog_ordering_args');

function custom_default_catalog_orderby($default_orderby) {
    return 'decimalwidth_asc';
}

function custom_catalog_ordering_args($args) {
    $orderby_value = isset($_GET['orderby']) ? wc_clean($_GET['orderby']) : apply_filters('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby'));
    
    if ($orderby_value == 'decimalwidth_asc') {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = 'decimalwidth';
    }
    
    return $args;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_catalog_orderby_options');

function custom_catalog_orderby_options($sortby) {
    unset($sortby['popularity']);
    unset($sortby['date']);
    unset($sortby['price']);
    unset($sortby['price-desc']);
    return $sortby;
}  


Each product attribute is a product custom taxonomy but not metadata, so you can NOT really sort products by a taxonomy (or a custom taxonomy): See this thread... What you could do is to create a product custom field (metadata) and fill in that custom field values from the product attribute with a custom SQL query via PHP my admin, then from that custom field you will be able to sort products.

Ok thanks for the info and suggestion. It seems I can automatically populate a meta field with the same info as the decimal width attribute. That seems to be working perfectly, but still the product sorting based on the newly created decimalwidth meta doesn't work at all.

https://imgur.com/uwzPoXf
https://woocommerce.com/document/custom-sorting-options-ascdesc/
https://imgur.com/5i0f6tS

In your screenshot, I don't really see an input field, but just a value: Are you sure that this is a custom field with meta_key = "decimalwidth" that has a real meta_value? Can you check in wp_postmeta table for a product to see if it's populated?
Now, you should add an edit at the end of your question with the explanations, screenshot(s) and your new code attempt please... Let me know here when it's done.

Thank you so much Loic. Yes, I thought I had code that automatically pulled in the attribute to the meta value, but was wrong. It displayed it on the product page but wasn't actually registering it in the database. Got the meta key registered in the database and now everything works perfectly like I had hoped. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction with the meta!

Done. Thanks again so much!
